# Translation of 追番

Tags: mandarin, word

What would 追番" translate to? It was displayed next to a heart icon on bilibili. From consulting a dictionary I believe hui in this context is pursue and fan is a measure word? I assume it means something like follow/subscribe but I would appreciate an explanation

Comment: 追 is zhuī, 追番 bkrs jargon  (Ru) chase down fresh anime

Comment: bilibili is a ACG site,  there are a lot of words from  anime or Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

> [番剧](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%95%AA%E5%89%A7)
>
> “番剧”是一个外来语词汇，意思为日本连载动画电视剧，属于二次元用户常用语。通常日本每年有四季动画剧，集中在1月、4月、7月、10月的某一个月份播出。因而类似美剧，番剧也是以季为单位，通常每周播出一集，一季12～13集居多。
>
> 中文名: 番剧
>
> 外文名: アニメ番組

番剧 refers to TV shows that come in multiple episodes and sometimes  multiple seasons

追番  obviously means "follow series"

*番剧- originally an anime fandom term:  アニメ番組 (anime series)*

Answer (score 1):

追 means "track (an TV show)".

新番 is originally from Japanese word 新番組. (Japanese word 番組 originally means "programs".) 新番 first be used as its original meaning, new programs. But it later been misused as the short of アニメ新番組, new TV anime (or even new anime).

If you saw this word on any ACG related website. It should probably means that "track this TV anime for next episodes".